# access modifiers in bash

Tags: bash, import, access-modifiers

Say I have a bash script and I want some variables to appear when sourced and others to only be accessible from within the script (both functions and variables). What's the convention to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried the `local` builtin from bash? see `help local`

Comment: yes, the values still appear after sourcing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `test.sh` is your bash script.

What you can do is extract all the common items and put them in `common.sh` which can be sourced by other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The `BASH_SOURCE` array helps you here:

Consider this script, `source.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} == "$0" ]]; then
    # this code is run when the script is _executed_
    foo=bar

    privFunc() { echo "running as a script"; }

    main() {
        privFunc
        publicFunc
    }
fi

# this code is run when script is executed or sourced
answer=42
publicFunc() { echo "Hello, world!"; }

echo "$0 - ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"

[[ ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} == "$0" ]] && main
```

Running it:

```sh
$ bash source.sh
source.sh - source.sh
running as a script
Hello, world!
```

Sourcing it:

```sh
$ source source.sh
bash - source.sh
$ declare -p answer
declare -- answer="42"
$ declare -p foo
bash: declare: foo: not found
$ publicFunc
Hello, world!
$ privFunc
bash: privFunc: command not found
$ main
bash: main: command not found
```